# What errors/exceptions do I need to handle with urllib2.Request / urlopen?

Tags: python

I have the following code to do a postback to a remote URL:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com', postBackData, { 'User-Agent' : 'My User Agent' })

try: 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    checksLogger.error('HTTPError = ' + str(e.code))
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    checksLogger.error('URLError = ' + str(e.reason))
except httplib.HTTPException, e:
    checksLogger.error('HTTPException')
```

The postBackData is created using a dictionary encoded using urllib.urlencode. checksLogger is a logger using [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

I have had a problem where this code runs when the remote server is down and the code exits (this is on customer servers so I don't know what the exit stack dump / error is at this time). I'm assuming this is because there is an exception and/or error that is not being handled. So are there any other exceptions that might be triggered that I'm not handling above?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add generic exception handler:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com', postBackData, { 'User-Agent' : 'My User Agent' })

try: 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    checksLogger.error('HTTPError = ' + str(e.code))
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    checksLogger.error('URLError = ' + str(e.reason))
except httplib.HTTPException, e:
    checksLogger.error('HTTPException')
except Exception:
    import traceback
    checksLogger.error('generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: is `checksLogger.error` a user defined function in your example?

Comment: @algotr8der: yeah, it's just copy'n'paste of logging in the question

Comment: socket.error (or its parent IOError) is another exception that you could usefully catch explicitly. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer

Answer (score 20):

From the [docs page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) `urlopen` entry, it looks like you just need to catch [URLError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError). If you really want to hedge your bets against problems within the urllib code, you can also catch `Exception` as a fall-back.  Do **not** just `except:`, since that will catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` also.

Edit: What I mean to say is, you're catching the errors it's supposed to throw.  If it's throwing something else, it's probably due to urllib code not catching something that it should have caught and wrapped in a `URLError`.  Even the stdlib tends to miss simple things like `AttributeError`.  Catching `Exception` as a fall-back (and logging what it caught) will help you figure out what's happening, without trapping `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: +1 for the link to the docs, and the clean advice on exceptions

Comment: +1 for letting me know what's the difference between except: and except Exception (at least one of them).

Comment: The Docs page is 404

Comment: @Priyank, not anymore :)

Answer (score 15):

```
$ grep "raise" /usr/lib64/python/urllib2.py
IOError); for HTTP errors, raises an HTTPError, which can also be
        raise AttributeError, attr
                raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
        # XXX raise an exception if no one else should try to handle
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        perform the redirect.  Otherwise, raise HTTPError if no-one
            raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
                raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code,
            raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), 401, "digest auth failed",
                raise ValueError("AbstractDigestAuthHandler doesn't know "
            raise URLError('no host given')
            raise URLError('no host given')
            raise URLError(err)
        raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
        raise URLError('file not on local host')
            raise IOError, ('ftp error', 'no host given')
            raise URLError(msg)
            raise IOError, ('ftp error', msg), sys.exc_info()[2]
            raise GopherError('no host given')
```

There is also the possibility of exceptions in urllib2 dependencies, or of exceptions caused by genuine bugs.

You are best off logging all uncaught exceptions in a file via a custom [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook). *The key rule of thumb here is to **never catch exceptions you aren't planning to correct**, and **logging is not a correction**.* So don't catch them just to log them.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch all exceptions and log what's get caught:

```
 import sys
 import traceback
 def formatExceptionInfo(maxTBlevel=5):
     cla, exc, trbk = sys.exc_info()
     excName = cla.__name__
     try:
         excArgs = exc.__dict__["args"]
     except KeyError:
         excArgs = "<no args>"
     excTb = traceback.format_tb(trbk, maxTBlevel)
     return (excName, excArgs, excTb)
 try:
     x = x + 1
 except:
     print formatExceptionInfo()
```

(Code from http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5821)

Also read [documentation on sys.exc_info](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).

Comment: Better to use "except Exception:" so you don't catch errors that are going to cause problems in your except handler.

Comment: Better to not catch exceptions at all if you're just logging them -- see my answer.

Comment: @Steven Huwig: yes, but I find that even using excepthook is clumsy - I'd better added some logging on the server, for example, somescript.py 2>/var/tmp/scrape.log

Answer (score 0):

I catch:

```
httplib.HTTPException
urllib2.HTTPError
urllib2.URLError
```

I believe this covers everything including socket errors.

Comment: `urllib2.HTTPError` is a subclass of `urllib2.URLError`, so catching the second one is enough