# Python handling socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, urllib2

When using Python 2.7 with `urllib2` to retrieve data from an API, I get the error `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`. Whats causing the error, and how should the error be handled so that the script does not crash?

**ticker.py**

```
def urlopen(url):
    response = None
    request = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
        print "HTTPError: {} ({})".format(url, err.code)
    except urllib2.URLError as err:
        print "URLError: {} ({})".format(url, err.reason)
    except httplib.BadStatusLine as err:
        print "BadStatusLine: {}".format(url)
    return response

def get_rate(from_currency="EUR", to_currency="USD"):
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=sl1&s=%s%s=X" % (
        from_currency, to_currency)
    data = urlopen(url)
    if "%s%s" % (from_currency, to_currency) in data:
        return float(data.strip().split(",")[1])
    return None


counter = 0
while True:

    counter = counter + 1
    if counter==0 or counter%10:
        rateEurUsd = float(get_rate('EUR', 'USD'))

    # does more stuff here
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/testApp/python/ticker.py", line 71, in <module>
    rateEurUsd = float(get_rate('EUR', 'USD'))
  File "/var/www/testApp/python/ticker.py", line 29, in get_exchange_rate
    data = urlopen(url)
  File "/var/www/testApp/python/ticker.py", line 16, in urlopen
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

Comment: On arch linux, get_rate works fine for me. Are you sure you aren't being filtered? Can you load that url in a browser?

Comment: @korylprince It works fine in a browser, and the script runs fine for a while before the error starts appearing. If I can't avoid the error, how should the error be handled so that it does not crash, and probably use the most recent value retrieved?

Answer (score 158):

> "Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying, leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly polite TCP/IP converseur. ([From other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434506/816449))

So you can't do anything about it, it is the issue of the server.

But you could use `try .. except` block to handle that exception:

```
from socket import error as SocketError
import errno

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
except SocketError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
        raise # Not error we are looking for
    pass # Handle error here.
```

Comment: Is it true that the administrator of the server usually uses this method to block the potential scraping requests by a client or is it more likely to be just an unintentional bug? Now I wonder if I'm blocked intentionally or not...

Comment: In some cases, it may happen due to a bug in another part of the system. In my case, there were many CLOSE_WAIT tcp connections in my server side and the number was bigger than server application could provide (java allows max 50 connections at a time). So my server side application was just denying new connection attempts by resetting the connection after approximately 50 CLOSE_WAIT hung connections.

Comment: not a native english speaker. What does "slamming the phone back on the hook." mean?

Comment: @Pinocchio I'm also not native speaker, but this also exists in my language and refers to obsolete phone technology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_hook

With old phones, when you pick up a phone, the hook automatically turned on the connection. When you put the phone back on the hook - it disconnected. So basically in modern language, it means "to press disconnect/red button, leave the call".

Comment: so if I have control over the server and the client--what can I do to fix this on the server end? Thank you!

Comment: @MikeSandstrom I think it very much depends on your server (maybe it's process got terminated because of some unexpected error), so it's better to ask a separate questions about this, providing more information about your server and request you are sending to it, etc...

Comment: no question privileges until next month sadly

Answer (score 20):

You can try to add some `time.sleep` calls to your code.

It seems like the server side limits the amount of requests per timeunit (hour, day, second) as a security issue. You need to guess how many (maybe using another script with a counter?) and adjust your script to not surpass this limit.

In order to avoid your code from crashing, try to catch this error with `try .. except` around the urllib2 calls.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to catch the error directly in the except clause with ConnectionResetError, better to isolate the right error.
This example also catches the timeout.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from socket import timeout

url = "http://......"
try: 
    string = urlopen(url, timeout=5).read()
except ConnectionResetError:
    print("==> ConnectionResetError")
    pass
except timeout: 
    print("==> Timeout")
    pass
```

Comment: This is not a correct answaer because pass an exception is like put to silent an critical error in your code. Reference to the Most Diabolic Anti Pattern in Pythn article https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/

Answer (score 3):

### there are 2 solution you can try.

1. request too frequently.
   try `sleep` after per request

```py
time.sleep(1)
```

2. the server detect the request client is python, so reject.
   add `User-Agent` in header to handle this.

```py
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    }
    try:
        res = requests.post("url", json=req, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

the second solution save me