# How to tell if requests.Session() is good?

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I have the following session-dependent code which must be run continuously.

#### Code

```
import requests
http = requests.Session()

while True:
    # if http is not good, then run http = requests.Session() again
    response = http.get(....)
    # process respons
    # wait for 5 seconds
```

Note: I moved the line `http = requests.Session()` out of the loop.

#### Issue

How to check if the session is *working*?

An example for a not *working* session may be after the web server is restarted. Or loadbalancer redirects to a different web server.

Comment: You are confusing a client session with a server session. While a server session can expire, you can create a new one in the same client session.

Answer (score 5):

The [`requests.Session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object is just a persistence and connection-pooling object to allow shared state between different HTTP request on the client-side.

If the server unexpectedly closes a session, so that it becomes invalid, the server probably would respond with some error-indicating HTTP status code.

Thus requests would raise an error. See [Errors and Exceptions](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions):

> All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises inherit from `requests.exceptions.RequestException`.

See the [extended classes of `RequestException`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_modules/requests/exceptions/).

#### Approach 1: implement open/close using `try/except`

Your code can catch such exceptions within a try/except-block.
It depends on the server's API interface specification how it will signal a invalidated/closed session. This signal response should be evaluated in the `except` block.

Here we use `session_was_closed(exception)` function to evaluate the exception/response and [`Session.close()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.close) to close the session correctly before opening a new one.

```py
import requests

# initially open a session object
s = requests.Session()

# execute requests continuously
while True:
    try:
        response = s.get(....)
        # process response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if session_was_closed(e):
            s.close()  # close the session
            s = requests.Session()  # opens a new session
        else:
            # process non-session-related errors
    # wait for 5 seconds
```

Depending on the server response of your case, implement the method `session_was_closed(exception)`.

#### Approach 2: automatically open/close using `with`

From [Advanced Usage, Session Objects](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> Sessions can also be used as context managers:
>
> ```
> with requests.Session() as s:
>     s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
> ```
>
> This will make sure the session is closed as soon as the with block is exited, even if unhandled exceptions occurred.

Comment: My code will `get` every 5 seconds. For the approach two, it will open/close for every call. Will it be any performance concern? BTW, is there any example of `session_was_closed`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 Approach 2 will open a new session each time it enters the `with` block. So your polling (loop) should be moved inside the with-block to reuse the session and benefit from connection-pooling.
For Approach 1, you can adjust the `session_was_closed` evaluation to your specification and expected server behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I would flip the logic and add a try-except.

```py
import requests
http = requests.Session()

while True:
    try:
        response = http.get(....)
    except requests.ConnectionException:
        http = requests.Session()
        continue
    # process respons
    # wait for 5 seconds
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34747831/9810067) for more info. I didn't test if the raised exception is that one, so please test it.