# Connection reset by peer in audiosocket

Tags: python, audio

in audio-socket server [refrense](https://pypi.org/project/audiosocket/) duration call, randomly call disconnected with below exception:

````
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
 self.run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/call_management/audiosocket_server/connection.py", line 228, in _process
 self.conn_sock.send(types.audio + PCM_SIZE + bytes(320))
 ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer```


why occur this exception? It disconnect call, how i fix it?
````

Comment: see this[questtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287669/handling-connectionreseterror), or you could trace network routes either its up or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.