# Simple Web Server Python

Tags: python-3.x, web, server

I'm having trouble getting my server to work. I'm trying to push a txt file to the local client. I keep getting an error with connection reset by peer. How do I fix this? Here is my code that I have.

```
import socket
from socket import *
from datetime import datetime
import sys

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = "127.0.0.2"  # Local client is going to be 127.0.0.1
PORT = 4300  # Open http://127.0.0.2:4300 in a browser
LOGFILE = "webserver.log"


def main():
    """Main loop"""
    with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(1)
        print('Listening on port {}'.format(PORT))
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("Waiting for client response")
        with conn:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                dt = data.decode()
                print(dt)
                if not data:
                    print('Connection closed')
                    break
                if data:
                    filename = 'alice30.txt'
                    f = open(filename,'rb')
                    l = f.read(1024)
                    while (l):
                        conn.sendall(l)
                        print('Sent ',repr(l))
                        l = f.read(1024)
                    f.close()
                else:
                    print("Invalid")
                    conn.sendall("Invalid Request".encode())

                print("Waiting for client response")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Traceback I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "webserver.py", line 24, in main
    data = conn.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I believe this isn't the same issue that the linked to duplicate. In the answers they said that is is the issue of the server. My code is the server... I think it has to deal with the bytes being sent back and forth.

Comment: Show the error with traceback please. And the file you are trying to push.

Comment: lol the file is alice and wonderland in in a txt file. The trace back is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "webserver.py", line 35, in main
    conn.sendall(l)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: Post that in your question please. You can't format a comment.

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python handling socket.error: \[Errno 104\] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer)