# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer from specific website | Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to check if a link is broken or not. For that I am sending an element (a link) from a list of dictionaries with a while loop and I am using urllib.request. The goal is to remove only broken links from the list. List contains links to different articles from https://jamanetwork.com/ and I want to be able to download articles that exist.

However I am getting a **ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**. 
I only get that error when I am trying to test links from https://jamanetwork.com/, and every page on https://jamanetwork.com/, but code seems to work fine for other websites.

My question is: am I missing something here or is it server side issue?

Here is my code (python3):

```
import urllib.request

i = 0
while i < (len(dicts)):
  url = dicts[i]['link']
  try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    status = f.getcode()
    i += 1
 except:
    del dicts[i]
```

Here is a traceback:

```
https://jamanetwork.com/
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-8d93b45dbd14> in <module>()
     22 print(url)
     23 
---> 24 with urllib.request.urlopen("https://jamanetwork.com/") as f:
     25   status = f.getcode()
     26   print(status)

12 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    629         """
    630         if buffer is not None:
--> 631             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    632         else:
    633             v = self._sslobj.read(len)

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you have internet issue ?

Comment: No, I also use google colab for that, don't know if that matters

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer). You can't resolve server error. But, you can handle it.

> So you can't do anything about it, it is the issue of the server.
>   But you could use try .. except block to handle that exception:

Try this code :

```
import urllib.request

i = 0
while i < (len(dicts)):
    url = dicts[i]['link']
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except:
        del dicts[i]
    else:
        with f:
            status = f.getcode()
            i += 1
```

Comment: The problem is that my list contains links to different articles from https://jamanetwork.com/ and I want to be able to download articles that exist. The code above just skips all of them, even if page exists, just because link returns ConnectionResetError

Comment: can you attach the different ?

Comment: Here is an example of broken link: https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2706122?resultClick=1 and a working one: https://jamanetwork.com/channels/health-forum/fullarticle/2760097?resultClick=1