# PyTorch Dataloader hangs when num_workers > 0

Tags: multiprocessing, pytorch, dataloader

PyTorch Dataloader hangs when num_workers > 0. The code hangs with only about `500 M` GPU memory usage.

System info: `NVIDIA-SMI 418.56 Driver Version: 418.56  CUDA Version: 10.1`.
The same issue appears with pytorch1.5 or pytorch1.6, codes are run in anaconda envs.

Note that this error appears when I run my script in terminal as  `python main.py`, but when I
debug the same code on Pycharm or VScode, or when I run the same code (in terminal) on
other machines, everything goes fine.
Any idea about the reason for this?

Here is the trace when I `ctrl c` the code in terminal:

```
  File "train.py", line 226, in main
    train_domain_adaptation(model, source_loader, target_loader, val_loader,
  File "/home/zhangyu/codes/person_seg/IntraDA/ADVENT/advent/domain_adaptation/train_UDA.py", line 326, in train_domain_adaptation
    train_advent(model, trainloader, targetloader, val_loader, cfg, group=group, fk_loader=fk_loader)
  File "/home/zhangyu/codes/person_seg/IntraDA/ADVENT/advent/domain_adaptation/train_UDA.py", line 114, in train_advent
    _, (images_source, labels, src_names, voc_ids, _) = trainloader_iter.__next__()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 363, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 974, in _next_data
    idx, data = self._get_data()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 931, in _get_data
    success, data = self._try_get_data()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 779, in _try_get_data
    data = self._data_queue.get(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/queue.py", line 179, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 306, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 25, in _pin_memory_loop
    r = in_queue.get(timeout=MP_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 116, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 282, in rebuild_storage_fd
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 57, in detach
    with _resource_sharer.get_connection(self._id) as conn:
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 87, in get_connection
    c = Client(address, authkey=process.current_process().authkey)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 508, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 752, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/home/zhangyu/anaconda3/envs/pt16/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I dont see any error! nor do I see any snippets of code! does it hang indefinitely ? how many cpu cores do you have? did you try with a smaller number?

Comment: There are about 32 cores on the machine. Any `num_workers>0` will cause the issue. Yes, it hangs indefinitely. The issue only appears when I run the python script in the terminal, so I think the code is fine.

Comment: Did you use any opencv functions in the dataloader? The messages just show that the main process is waiting for the dataloader processes with really no meaningful information.

Comment: any update? i am facing exactly this same issue in windows 10
i used,
anaconda virtual environment where i have,
python 3.8.5
pytorch 1.7.0
cuda 11.0
cudnn 8004
gpu rtx 3060ti
Is CUDA available: Yes

Comment: You can read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20568874/16310106 because you have the same error.

Comment: same issue here. Any update?

Comment: How about CPU memory? Did you check if you have ran out of that?