# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 104] Discord bot connection reset due to peer error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a Discord bot that collects time spent in voice channels, counts sent messages, forms the rating, and pushes the rating into the picture. The Bot is accumulating two ratings: one for the week and one for the month. And I have two functions that generate images and send them via chat. My code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import time
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guild_messages = True, members = True, guilds = True, voice_states = True))

myFont = ImageFont.truetype('minecraft.ttf', 39)

ever = {}
week = {}
month = {}
active = {}
issent = 0
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global ever
  global week
  global month
  print("Ready")
  for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        ever[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
        week[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
        month[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
  
  client.loop.create_task(month_vipe())
  client.loop.create_task(week_vipe())
            

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ever[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
    week[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
    month[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  ever[ctx.author.id]["text"] = ever[ctx.author.id]["text"] + 1
  week[ctx.author.id]["text"] = week[ctx.author.id]["text"] + 1
  month[ctx.author.id]["text"] = month[ctx.author.id]["text"] + 1

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  global ever
  global week
  global month
  user = member.id
  if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
    print(f"{user} joined")
    active[user] = time.time()

  if after.channel is None and before.channel is not None:
    
    print(f"{user} left")
    ever[user]["voice"] += time.time() - active[user]
    week[user]["voice"] += time.time() - active[user]
    month[user]["voice"] += time.time() - active[user]


async def week_vipe():
  global week
  while True:
    reyt = {}
    print('week vipr func')
    for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        voice = round(week[member.id]["voice"] / 120)
        reyt[member.id] = week[member.id]["text"] + voice
    sorted_reyt = {k: b for k, b in sorted(reyt.items(), key=lambda element: element[1], reverse=True)}
    my_image = Image.open("maket.png")
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    text = f"недiльний рейтинг"
    image_editable.text((230,131), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
    my_image.save("result.png")
    for i in range(3):
      keys_list = list(sorted_reyt)
      username = client.get_user(keys_list[i])
      reyting = sorted_reyt[keys_list[i]]
      if i+1 == 1:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,211), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
      if i+1 == 2:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,429), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
      if i+1 == 3:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,647), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
    chat = client.get_channel(1005796493757780019)
    await chat.send(file=discord.File('result.png'))
    print('week reyt sent')
    for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        week[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
    await asyncio.sleep(60)#604800


async def month_vipe():
  global month
  global issent
  while True:
    reyt = {}
    print('month vipr func')
    for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        voice = round(month[member.id]["voice"] / 120)
        reyt[member.id] = month[member.id]["text"] + voice
    sorted_reyt = {k: b for k, b in sorted(reyt.items(), key=lambda element: element[1], reverse=True)}
    my_image = Image.open("maket.png")
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    text = f"місячний рейтинг"
    image_editable.text((230,131), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
    my_image.save("result.png")
    for i in range(3):
      keys_list = list(sorted_reyt)
      username = client.get_user(keys_list[i])
      reyting = sorted_reyt[keys_list[i]]
      if i+1 == 1:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,211), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
      if i+1 == 2:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,429), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
      if i+1 == 3:
        my_image = Image.open("result.png")
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
        text = f"{i+1}. {username}"
        image_editable.text((620,647), text, (125, 95, 53), font=myFont)
        my_image.save("result.png")
    chat = client.get_channel(1005796493757780019)
    print('sending month reyt')
    await chat.send(file=discord.File('result.png'))
    print('month reyt sent')
    issent = 1
    for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        month[member.id] = {"voice": 0, "text": 0}
    await asyncio.sleep(240)#2592000
```

And problem with functions

> client.loop.create_task(month_vipe()) and
> client.loop.create_task(week_vipe())
> The error occurs in the function that is run first.
> Full Traceback:

[image: I am sorry! I can’t copy it :(]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the errors as a code block, not images. As well, please include a [mcve]. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a network issue which is hard to pinpoint. It also can't be a rate limit issue, because discord.py already handles rate limits.

See here for more: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2596

And from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer):

> "Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying, leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly polite TCP/IP converseur.