# How to debug a "Connection reset by peer" issue in urllib3 when upgrading from v1 to v2

Tags: python, ssl, https, urllib3

Does anyone have any pointers or advice on how to get to the bottom of a "Connection reset by peer" issue in Python with urllib3?

I have been using using urllib3 version 1 for year but have a project that when I swap from urllib3==1.26.18 to urllib3>=2.0.0 my requests that were working now fail.

In the real example the requests use the requests package with HTTPBasicAuth but even if I strip that out and use something as basic as the below I hit the issue.

```
import urllib3
c = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "HTTPS-endpoint-here"
r = c.request('GET', url)
```

The problem appears to be with one site but having run it through SSL labs I've confirmed that the certificates on the site are installed okay and that it supports TLS 1.2 as well as TLS 1.1. It doesn't support TLS1.3 but that's okay as urlib3 v2 supports 1.2 by default.

I've tested using Python 3.11.1 and 3.11.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

I didn't have pyopenssl installed but I've installed that and no luck

If I run `openssl version` I can see I'm using `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`

`python -m requests.help`

currently returns

```
{
  "chardet": {
    "version": null
  },
  "charset_normalizer": {
    "version": "2.0.10"
  },
  "cryptography": {
    "version": ""
  },
  "idna": {
    "version": "3.3"
  },
  "implementation": {
    "name": "CPython",
    "version": "3.11.1"
  },
  "platform": {
    "release": "5.15.0-88-generic",
    "system": "Linux"
  },
  "pyOpenSSL": {
    "openssl_version": "",
    "version": null
  },
  "requests": {
    "version": "2.31.0"
  },
  "system_ssl": {
    "version": "1010106f"
  },
  "urllib3": {
    "version": "2.0.7"
  },
  "using_charset_normalizer": true,
  "using_pyopenssl": false
}
```

As I can make requests to other HTTPS endpoints include HTTPBin with basicauth the issues must be with the endpoint I'm requesting (a clients) but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to look at next to try to work out what's wrong.

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

**Update**

Here is an example that can connect with urlib3 version 1.26.18 but if you then upgrade to 2.0.7 you immediately receive the "Connection reset by peer" exception

```
import urllib3
c = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://api.hicargo.com/BoxDocs/UK/JobDocs/HE630819/99054-77 4500187758.pdf"
r = c.request("GET", url)
print(r.status)
```

That end-point requires authentication so a "HTTP 401" is the expected response.

Comment: by any chance you are using threading ?you can refer few solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568216/python-handling-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer add sleep in your subsequent call

Comment: Hard to tell with the few information provided. But it can be useful to narrow down the error to make a packet capture to determine at which stage of the connection the problem occurs, i.e. if at the start of the TCP connection, inside the TLS handshake or after the successful TLS handshake.

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm not using threading, it's essentially the code I posted above, downgrading fixed the issue I was having so it's something that's only picked up in the change from v1 to v2 im urlib3.

Comment: I've updated my post with a full example that works with 1.26.16 but fails with 2.0.7